# Locate Pointer setting blocks ctrl key

Tags: gnome, keyboard, system-settings

So, I turned on Locate Pointer setting under Universal Access, and my ctrl key was not working after that, then I tried disabling it and ctrl key started working again.

My question is: how do I have Locate Pointer on but be able to use ctrl key?

Comment: Ctrl key is the trigger for locating pointer by default..you need to choose other one

Comment: I remember than on Windows, it used to locate the pointer AND have the default ctrl key behavior (which is what I want), but on Ubuntu, it overwrites it.